# How to use Fabric with proxy servers?

Tags: python, fabric

I have one server `server1`. I would like to connect to the `server2` via the `server1` using Fabric script and run my commands.

I tried to run code like `run("ssh server2")`:

```
@task()
deploy():
    with run("ssh server2"):
        # some code here...
        with cd('my directory...'):
            pass
```

But when I run the task like this I get a console for the input (console of my second server) instead of the execution of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Configure](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/) the "proxy server", aka "jump host", in your `~/.ssh/config`. Make sure it works from command line.

Then use the same in Fabric.